# Format a number to string with thousand separators and always has 2 digits after decimal point in swift

Tags: string, swift, numbers, string-formatting

How to format `5432.1` to `5,432.10`.

We can use string formatting to force it always show 2 digtis.

```
let n = 5432.1
let s = String(format: "%.2f", n)   //5432.10
```

We can use number formatter to add thousand separators.

```
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .DecimalStyle
let s2 = formatter.stringFromNumber(n)  //5,432.1
```

But how can we combine both? Are there any way to convert that directly? 
Or do I have to manipulate those two string results to get the final result?

Comment: `formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2`

Comment: @Mike Pollard thanks

Comment: comon @Mike provide an answer for us to upmark and you to get the credit!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [`NSNumberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSNumberFormatter/minimumFractionDigits).

```
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .DecimalStyle
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
let s2 = formatter.stringFromNumber(n)  //5,432.10
```